the canvas is showing down
import customtkinter as ctk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import tkinter

def GoToAdkar():
    Main_Canvas.pack_forget()

window = ctk.CTk()
window.geometry("450x600")
Main_Frame = ctk.CTkFrame(window,width=450,height=600)
Main_Frame.pack()
Main_Canvas = ctk.CTkCanvas(Main_Frame, width=450, height=600,background="green",highlightthickness=0)
img= ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("main.png"))

Wel_img = tkinter.Label(Main_Frame,image=img)
Wel_img.pack()

Main_Canvas.create_text(225,40,text="اذكار المسلم",font=("Arial",40),fill="#262626")
Main_Canvas.create_text(225,38,text="اذكار المسلم",font=("Arial",40),fill="grey")
Main_Canvas.create_text(225,36,text="اذكار المسلم",font=("Arial",40),fill="white")

Main_Canvas.create_line(70,75,400,75,width=4,fill="green")
Main_Canvas.create_line(90,85,380,85,width=4,fill="green")
Main_Canvas.pack()

AdkarGoButton = ctk.CTkButton(Main_Canvas, text="بعض اذكار المسلم",corner_radius=0,
                            font=("Arial",30), width= 200,height=50,fg_color="#37692f"
                            ,hover_color="#264d20",command=GoToAdkar)
AdkarGoButton.place(x=125,y=130)

window.mainloop()

I want to render the main_canvas over the image, no down.
The wel_img is the background and the main_canvas is the elements but it's showing down not over the background like required.
Idk I was trying and I didn't figure it.

If you want to see the image as background, you should create the image inside the canvas using .create_image() instead.

you may need to create CTkCanvas after Label and it may need to use place() to put one object on another. But Label can't be transparent so background will be behind green label. Real background you can get with .create_image()

If you want to use an image as background, you can put the image into the canvas using .create_image():
import customtkinter as ctk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import tkinter

def GoToAdkar():
    Main_Canvas.pack_forget()

window = ctk.CTk()
window.geometry("450x600")

Main_Frame = ctk.CTkFrame(window, width=450, height=600)
Main_Frame.pack()

Main_Canvas = ctk.CTkCanvas(Main_Frame, width=450, height=600,
                            background="green", highlightthickness=0)
Main_Canvas.pack()

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("main.png"))
# put the image into canvas using .create_image()
Main_Canvas.create_image(225, 300, image=img, anchor="c")

Main_Canvas.create_text(225, 40, text="اذكار المسلم", font=("Arial",40), fill="#262626")
Main_Canvas.create_text(225, 38, text="اذكار المسلم", font=("Arial",40), fill="grey")
Main_Canvas.create_text(225, 36, text="اذكار المسلم", font=("Arial",40), fill="white")

Main_Canvas.create_line(70, 75, 400, 75, width=4, fill="green")
Main_Canvas.create_line(90, 85, 380, 85, width=4, fill="green")

AdkarGoButton = ctk.CTkButton(Main_Canvas, text="بعض اذكار المسلم", corner_radius=0,
                              font=("Arial",30), width=200, height=50, fg_color="#37692f",
                              hover_color="#264d20", command=GoToAdkar)
#AdkarGoButton.place(x=125, y=130)
# better use create_window() to put tkinter widget into the canvas
Main_Canvas.create_window(225, 130, window=AdkarGoButton)

window.mainloop()

